# New interface based on an interface's keys

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create yet another interface from the `ImportAccountsState` but this time omitting the `StateVariable` interface. I want to do it the TypeScript way without defining it manually again.

```
interface StateVariable<T> {
  value: T;
  setValue: (value: T) => void;
}

interface ImportAccountsState {
  isDialogOpen: StateVariable<boolean>;
  organization: StateVariable<string>;
  isOrganizationValid: StateVariable<boolean>;
}
```

I want my end result to be like so

```
interface ImportAccountsState {
  isDialogOpen: boolean;
  organization: string;
  isOrganizationValid: boolean;
}
```

I kind of made a start with `keyof ImportAccountsState` but couldn't figure out how to map it to whatever type is inside the angle brackets `<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mapped types for this purpose

```js
interface StateVariable<T> {
    value: T;
    setValue: (value: T) => void;
}

interface ImportAccountsState {
    isDialogOpen: StateVariable<boolean>;
    organization: StateVariable<string>;
    isOrganizationValid: StateVariable<boolean>;
}


type Result = {
    [Prop in keyof ImportAccountsState]: ImportAccountsState[Prop]['value']
}
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

> Would it be far more complex if ImportAccountsState was generic?

```js
interface StateVariable<T> {
    value: T;
    setValue: (value: T) => void;
}
// not sure where you want to use T generic
interface ImportAccountsState {
    isDialogOpen: StateVariable<boolean>;
    organization: StateVariable<string>;
    isOrganizationValid: StateVariable<boolean>;
}


type Result<T extends Record<PropertyKey, { value: unknown }>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop]['value']
}
```

> I am getting an error when using Result
> Just use `type` instead of interface:

```js
// not sure where you want to use T generic
type ImportAccountsState = {
    isDialogOpen: StateVariable<boolean>;
    organization: StateVariable<string>;
    isOrganizationValid: StateVariable<boolean>;
}
```

`types` have index signature if you want to constraint it

OR move constraint inside the iteration:

```js
interface StateVariable<T> {
    value: T;
    setValue: (value: T) => void;
}
// not sure where you want to use T generic
interface ImportAccountsState {
    isDialogOpen: StateVariable<boolean>;
    organization: StateVariable<string>;
    isOrganizationValid: StateVariable<boolean>;
}


type Util<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends { value: unknown } ? T[Prop]['value'] : never
}

type Result = Util<ImportAccountsState> // ok
```

Comment: Would it be far more complex if `ImportAccountsState` was generic?

Comment: Updated. Not complex. You just have to add generic everywhere where you are using `ImportAccountsState`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant if I wasn't using `ImportAccountState` but an interface with different keys but having `StateVariable` as values too.

Comment: Something like `[Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop][...]`

Comment: I am getting an error when using `Result<ImportAccountsState>` - Type 'ImportAccountsState' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<PropertyKey, { value: unknown; }>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'ImportAccountsState'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type to extract the generic type from `StateVariable<T>`:

```
type ExtractGeneric<T extends StateVariable<any>> = 
    T extends StateVariable<infer TT> ? TT : never;
```

Here, we can be sure that because `T` is constrained to be of type `StateVariable<any>` that the `never` branch above will never happen because the type-checker will spew.

Now we can create a mapped type that makes use of the `ExtractGeneric` type:

```
type MappedStateVariableRecord<T extends Record<keyof T, StateVariable<any>>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ExtractGeneric<T[P]>
}
```

then use this type on your `ImportAccountsState`:

```
type MappedImportAccountsState = MappedStateVariableRecord<ImportAccountsState>
```

See [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpAanKw4BGANhADwAqAfMgN4BQyyAbnEQK4QBcy5A3A8gDOEMDnZdkAChbju5AJTIAvNSYB7YABN+AXzp1QkWIhQBJALYAHNVDABBBAjVtwg9JhT1GwQQBF8RGoA5gDylhAg3O7YuPjEZARqaiRwIJT8jDZBqcAAXpjAapFoGDF4hCSkgmB4IEHpAj4hUNkgeQVFYlpRpRA45fGkickQqQ16+mAAnuHIAKIAHjWIYADiEdDACBTIEEsRmoIlHv1xlalTlNRKPLv7IIfHZWdkoDDQPFTIAPyfyNwgCBMaD8OjTWYAWTglnCmmifViFQgACUIE4oJodntIA8jqj0ZiANYQKZqGA8AA0TwRA3OIEuV2UtAEAG0AArIUDIYmk8nkAC63EWywQaw2eG25HZ-ModAm4JQUJhEE0FmstgcThcYDcvSZSth8NOSPxNkxaps9kczlc8MoQA)